# Delphi: Use TidHTTPServer for transfer file and monitoring byte send for single request

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

Using `TIdHTTPServer` (Indy 10.6), how do track how many bytes are sent to the client (user browser) for each request (on close connection)?

```
procedure onCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
begin
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create('C:/HugeFile.zip', fmOpenRead or fmShareCompat);
    AResponseInfo.ContentLength := AResponseInfo.ContentStream.Size;
    AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;
    AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream.Free;
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := nil;
end;
```

eg, in a log file:

```
2014-11-06 20:32:00 - IPAddress 84.XXX.XXX.XXX download 1000000 Bytes (100%)
2014-11-05 16:05:00 - IPAddress 72.XXX.XXX.XXX download 500000  Bytes (50%)
```

Comment: What Indy version are you using? What would downloading 50% of a file represent? Are you wanting to log incremental progress (eg., IPAddress 72.xxx.xxx.xxx download 100000 bytes (10%), IPAddress 72.xxx.xxx.xxx download 150000 bytes (15%), etc)?

Comment: Your code can be shortened: only `AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(...)` is required. Indy configures and writes the response, and releases the stream.

Comment: @KenWhite `What Indy version are you using?` 10.6; `What would downloading 50% of a file represent?` client close connection at 50% of download;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to output a log at the end of the transfer saying how many bytes were sent, you can derive a new class from `TFileStream` and override its destructor to output a log message showing the stream's current `Position` relative to its `Size`.  Whatever other information you need to log can be passed to the constructor and saved so the destructor can use it.

For example:

```
type
  TMyFileStream = class(TFileStream)
  private
    FContext: TIdContext;
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string; AContext: TIdContext);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyFileStream.Create(const AFileName: string; AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  inherited Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareCompat);
  FContext := AContext;
end;

destructor TMyFileStream.Destroy;
var
  LPos, LSize: Int64;
  LPercent: Integer;
begin
  LPos := Position;
  LSize := Size;
  if LSize <> 0 then
    LPercent := (LPosition * 100) div LSize
  else
    LPercent := 100;
  MyLogFile.WriteLine(Format('%s IPAddress %s download %d Bytes (%d%%)', [FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS', Now), AContext.Binding.PeerIP, LPos, LPercent]);
  inherited;
end;

procedure onCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMyFileStream.Create('C:/HugeFile.zip', AContext);
end;
```

Comment: to track downloads with OnCommandGet I found :`AContext.Connection.OnWorkBegin := OnWorkBegin;`,
`AContext.Connection.OnWork := OnWork;`,
`AContext.Connection.OnWorkEnd := OnWorkEnd;`.  The `OnWork..` events have an `AWorkMode` parameter to tell
you which direction data is flowing - `wmWrite` (downloading) or `wmRead` (uploading) and `AWorkCountMax` the number of bytes uploaded or downloaded

Comment: alternatively I can use onWorkBegin, onWork, onWorkEnd??

Comment: If you need live statistics while the transfer is in progress, yes.